# How Field properties are identified by RFT tool

Tags: rft

```
Properties = .class='Html.INPUT.text'
      ,.name='deviceNUM'
      ,.classIndex='3'
      ,.id='deviceNUM_I'
      ,.type='text'
```

What  is `.calss = 'Html.INPUT.text' & ,.classIndex='3'

How these properties are calculated  by RFT

Can anyone please explain

Answer (score 0):

These are read by RFT from the HTML source you're trying to automate. When you record an action against an object on your HTML, RFT reads its properties.